# Generalizing creation and annihilation operators to multiple field Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, commutator

### **Introduction:**

For the following Lagrangian:

$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi\partial^\mu \phi - \frac{1}{2}m^2 \phi^2
$$

We mode expand the field and its conjugate momentum (Heisenberg picture) as,

$$
\phi(x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 E_p}} [a_p e^{-i p\cdot x} + a_p {}^\dagger e^{i p \cdot x}]
$$

and

$$
\pi(y) = \int \frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3} (-i) \sqrt{\frac{E_q}{2}} [a_q e^{-i q\cdot y} - a_q {}^\dagger e^{i q \cdot y}]
$$

with the following equal-time commutation relation,

$$
[\phi(x),\pi(y)] = i \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{y})
$$

where all other commutators vanish.

By using inverse Fourier transforms, from this commutation relation we can derive,

$$
[\phi(p),\pi(q)] = i (2\pi)^3 \delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}+\vec{q})
$$

where all other commutators vanish.

We can again use an inverse Fourier transform to express a and a dagger in terms of the momentum space expression for phi and pi,

$$
a_p=\sqrt{\frac{2E_p}{2}} \phi(p) + i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}} \pi(p)
$$

$$
a_p^\dagger = a_-p^\dagger = \sqrt{\frac{2E_p}{2}} \phi(p) - i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}} \pi(p) 
$$

Using this momentum space commutation relation, as well these expressions for a and a dagger, we can commute,

$$[a_p, a_q^\dagger] = (2\pi)^3 \delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}-\vec{q})$$

---

### Question:

Now... consider the following Lagrangian:

$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \phi^i)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\mu^2 (\phi^i)^2 - \frac{\lambda}{4}[(\phi^i)^2]^2
$$

Now (according to my source material — [Lancaster and Blundell's QFT for the Gifted Amateur](https://www.dropbox.com/s/61088nq1rwjbdwm/Lancaster%20and%20Blundell%27s%20QFTGA%20excerpt.pdf?dl=0)) the equal time commutation reads

$$
[\phi_a(x),\pi_b(y)] = i \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{y}) \delta_{ab}
$$

I am struggling to derive (via the same method as above) the same commutation relation for a and a dagger that the authors do here (see link):

$$[a_{\mathbf{p}a}, a_{\mathbf{q}b}^\dagger] = \delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}-\vec{q})\delta_{ab}$$

notably, no $(2\pi)^3$ as before.

However, I get practically the same as I got above, specifically,

$$
[a_{\mathbf{p}a}, a_{\mathbf{q}b}^\dagger] = (2\pi)^3 \delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}-\vec{q})\delta_{ab}$$

It has got to be in the the commutation relation for the momentum space phi and pi right?! Can anyone point out where the above derivation will differ for multiple fields?

Comment: Hmm! Note a difference in convention. I defined the mode expansion of phi and pi as 
$$
\phi(x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 E_p}} [a_p e^{-i p\cdot x} + a_p {}^\dagger e^{i p \cdot x}]
$$
where as the authors in my source have a different factor of $2\pi$ in the measure,
$$
\phi(x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 E_p}} [a_p e^{-i p\cdot x} + a_p {}^\dagger e^{i p \cdot x}]
$$

Comment: This could very well be the cause of my confusion. Any one expound on what the effect of this difference could be?

Comment: The factors appearing in the Fourier transform are purely a matter of convention. Some authors (e.g. Weinberg) don't even put the $\sqrt{2 E_p}$ factors in. As a result, the commutators of the creation/annihilation operators as well as the factors appearing in the normalization of Fock states will also change. But the spectrum of the Hamiltonian will not. As an exercise, try replacing these factors with arbitrary constants and carry through the calculation to see how they fall out of physical observables like the spectrum.

Comment: Thank for the assurance, indeed I checked some other conventions and these authors use a few different things.